# Switch between socket.io servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Could someone explain to me how I can get a socket.io client to connect to server A -> disconnect and then connect to server B ?

Cheers

EDIT: here is the code I'm having problems with

```
login.on('connect', function (data) { 
    console.log('Connected to login server');
});

login.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Disconnected from login server');
});

login.on('login', function (data) {
    // set the connection details for the storage server
    storage = io.connect('http://'+data.node);

    // Disconnect from the login server
    login.disconnect();
});


storage.on('connect', function (data) {
  console.log('Connected to storage server');
});
```

Storage on Connect never triggers.. Why?

Comment: var socket = io('serverA'); ... socket = io('serverB'); ?

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani say server A returns an address in which the client needs to connect for serverB how do properly do that?

Comment: store address in a var and then use that var to connect new socket.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani I'll give it a go again and get back with you with some code.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani I have updated my first post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
login.on('connect', function (data) { 
    console.log('Connected to login server');
});

login.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Disconnected from login server');
});

login.on('login', function (data) {
    // set the connection details for the storage server
    storage = io.connect('http://'+data.node);

    storage.on('connect', function (data) {
       console.log('Connected to storage server');
    });

    // Disconnect from the login server
    login.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: so for every instance on storage will need to be defined within the login.on login? There must be a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: try defining storage out of function and just connect it in login.on login function.

Comment: I have storage defined as var storage; defined outside of the login function but still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: did you checked your url? does it really connects to server?

Comment: Yes. Server B console logs an incoming connection on.connected